# Importing in Postgres throws error after doing COPY command

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, csv, pgadmin

I am trying to import data from csv file to my postgres table using command line, and have tried `COPY` as well, but every time it give me the following error, can anyone please help me where am I going wrong, as I am first time using Postgres, and after studying about I came to know that I can use `COPY` command to import and export data into csv and to table.

Below is me table schema where I am trying to import the `csv file`

```
create table tdummy2
(
number1 integer,
digit integer,
type_digit integer,
total integer,
word character varying(256),
apk character varying(256),
version1 character varying(256),
created  timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
updated  timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);
```

and this is how my csv file looks:

```
number1;"digit";"type_digit";"total";"word";"apk";"version1"
8;88444;34;97;"yt";"kjk";"vrt"
8;88444;34;97;"yt";"kjk";"vrt"
56;88444;34;97;"yt";"kjk";"vrt"
67;88444;34;97;"yt";"kjk";"vrt"
```

And this is the error I am getting while running the `COPY` command from command line

```
dummy_table=# COPY tdummy2 FROM 'C:\Users\user1\Documents\user1\import.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "number1;digit;type_digit;total;word;apk;version1"
CONTEXT:  COPY tdummy2, line 1, column number1: "number1;digit;type_digit;total;word;apk;version1"

dummy_table=#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file is semicolon delimited, but you've told PostgreSQL it's comma-delimited.

Try

```
COPY tdummy2 FROM 'C:\Users\user1\Documents\user1\import.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV;
                                                                        ^^^
                                                                      semicolon
```

and see if that helps.

If the CSV has a header, specify the `HEADER` option.

Comment: Thanks craig Ringer, I have noticed that too and changed the same but it throws me different error saying below: `dummy_table=# COPY tdummy2 FROM 'C:\Users\user1\Documents\user1\import.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "number1"
CONTEXT:  COPY tdummy2, line 1, column number1: "number1"`

Comment: @akiiddweeber You need the `HEADER` option to tell Pg the first row is a header. See the manual for `COPY`.